# How to move xcart from localhost to server

Tags: php

I am trying to move xcart from localhost to sever I have made the the changes in files config.php ,top.inc.php I have deleted the content of templates_c folder,but my site does'nt runs yet can somebody give me the solution I will be greatly thankfull.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with this..write these lines in your config file

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'localhost')  
{
    define('SITE_PATH','http://localhost/your project name/'); 
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set('display_errors','on'); 
}
else 
{
    define('SITE_PATH','http://www.yourwesbite.com/');      
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors','off');        
}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt produces any output.it displays the error

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition.

    www.mysitename.com/ (port 80) 

Please forward this error screen to www.mysitename.com's WebMaster.

Comment: there may b header problem ( header recycling )

Comment: what's that header recycling i don't know i am an newbie